# Ubuntu server freezes

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, file-server

I'm trying to get to the bottom of an issue with my home server which keeps freezing after different periods of time (ranging from 3 - 7 days).

It's currently running Ubuntu server:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

But the issue also occurred with Ubuntu desktop (usually after just one or two days). Details of the machine are below; the only modification I made was to replace the existing HDD with an SSD (Crucial_CT240M50, details below)

Based on other discussion around isses with SSDs, I've tried adding the following to `/etc/default/grub`:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="libata.force=noncq"`

I've run memtest but only for a few hours.

I had a screen session monitoring the output of `journalctl` which I've included below. I can't see anything obvious in it.

```
$ sudo lshw

myserver               
    description: Laptop
    product: Latitude E6410
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    version: 0001
    serial: XXXXXX
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=laptop uuid=4c4c4544-0046-3510-8057-cac04f335131
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 04373Y
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A03
       serial: /JF5W3Q1/CN1296113H00EB/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A09
          date: 05/26/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.37.5
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 1359MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 533MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=1 microcode=7 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3-Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 19
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: HMT325S6BFR8C-H9
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 0
             serial: 20739780
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: HMT325S6BFR8C-H9
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 1
             serial: 20539780
             slot: DIMM_B
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             logical name: /dev/fb0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
             configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1280,800
             resources: irq:26 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:70b0(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 05
             serial: 5c:26:0a:44:b8:92
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-39-generic firmware=0.12-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:24 memory:f6900000-f691ffff memory:f6980000-f6980fff ioport:7040(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f6970000-f69703ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.15.0-39-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             logical name: card0
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D1
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D3
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:f6960000-f6963fff
           *-input:0
                product: HDA Intel MID Dock Mic
                physical id: 0
                logical name: input10
                logical name: /dev/input/event9
           *-input:1
                product: HDA Intel MID Mic
                physical id: 1
                logical name: input11
                logical name: /dev/input/event10
           *-input:2
                product: HDA Intel MID Dock Line Out
                physical id: 2
                logical name: input12
                logical name: /dev/input/event11
           *-input:3
                product: HDA Intel MID Headphone
                physical id: 3
                logical name: input13
                logical name: /dev/input/event12
           *-input:4
                product: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                physical id: 4
                logical name: input14
                logical name: /dev/input/event13
           *-input:5
                product: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=7
                physical id: 5
                logical name: input15
                logical name: /dev/input/event14
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:6000(size=4096) memory:f5500000-f68fffff ioport:f6a00000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:f4100000-f54fffff ioport:f6c00000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 35
                serial: 18:3d:a2:1e:5c:14
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-39-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 6000-4.uc ip=192.168.8.132 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:27 memory:f4100000-f4101fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=8192) memory:f0400000-f2cfffff ioport:f6e00000(size=2097152)
           *-pcmcia
                description: CardBus bridge
                product: CardBus bridge
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 02
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pcmcia bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=yenta_cardbus latency=176 maxlatency=5 mingnt=128
                resources: irq:18 memory:f2c40000-f2c40fff ioport:2000(size=256) ioport:2400(size=256) memory:f0400000-f17fffff memory:f1800000-f1bfffff
           *-generic
                description: MMC Host
                product: MMC/SD Host Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
                logical name: mmc0
                version: 03
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:f2c30000-f2c300ff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 0.4
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.4
                version: 03
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi pm pciexpress ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f2c00000-f2c007ff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:f2d00000-f40fffff ioport:f7000000(size=2097152)
        ...
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0b00
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device PNP0303
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device BCM0102
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device PNP0401
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
           *-pnp00:05
                product: PnP device DLL040a
                physical id: 5
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 aux
           *-pnp00:06
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 6
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi1
             logical name: scsi2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:25 ioport:7090(size=8) ioport:7080(size=4) ioport:7070(size=8) ioport:7060(size=4) ioport:7020(size=32) memory:f6940000-f69407ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: Crucial_CT240M50
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
                version: MU05
                serial: 14160C16BA88
                size: 223GiB (240GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=257b4e05-6829-4f67-9f7a-2fe9b6cd3ef3 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
              *-volume:0
                   description: BIOS Boot partition
                   vendor: EFI
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sdb1
                   serial: f4f11d64-5ae1-420e-b322-2f6a02920ca5
                   capacity: 1023KiB
                   capabilities: nofs
              *-volume:1
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sdb2
                   logical name: /boot
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: eb2f587e-299c-49dd-a64a-e00f40ac938f
                   size: 2GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2022-06-15 13:59:12 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2022-06-21 09:50:00 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2022-06-21 09:50:00 state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: EFI partition
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sdb3
                   serial: CZGUeW-IDhM-skwK-ZpMa-ggTo-EFX0-drrp9s
                   size: 221GiB
                   capabilities: lvm2
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: DVD+-RW GU40N
                vendor: HL-DT-ST
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: A102
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f6930000-f69300ff ioport:7000(size=32)
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel ips latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f6920000-f6920fff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.2
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:3f:02.3
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-battery
       product: DELL ND8CG0C
       vendor: SMP
       physical id: 1
       version: 12/26/2010
       serial: 0753
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       configuration: voltage=11.1V
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 2
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
  *-input:0
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: Sleep Button
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:3
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input3
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:4
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 7
       logical name: input4
       logical name: /dev/input/event4
       logical name: input4::capslock
       logical name: input4::numlock
       logical name: input4::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:5
       product: AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad
       physical id: 8
       logical name: input6
       logical name: /dev/input/event6
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:6
       product: AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick
       physical id: 9
       logical name: input7
       logical name: /dev/input/event5
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:7
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: a
       logical name: input8
       logical name: /dev/input/event7
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:8
       product: Dell WMI hotkeys
       physical id: b
       logical name: input9
       logical name: /dev/input/event8
       capabilities: platform
```

```
$inxi

CPU: dual core Intel Core i5 M 560 (-MT MCP-)
speed/min/max: 1525/1199/2667 MHz Kernel: 5.15.0-39-generic x86_64 Up: 5m
Mem: 484.8/3786.8 MiB (12.8%) Storage: 2.95 TiB (0.3% used) Procs: 161
Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

```
$journalctl

Jun 30 00:11:38 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Jun 30 00:17:01 myserver CRON[28905]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 00:17:01 myserver CRON[28906]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 00:17:01 myserver CRON[28905]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 00:19:16 myserver smbd[28548]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Jun 30 00:11:38 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Jun 30 00:17:01 myserver CRON[28905]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 00:17:01 myserver CRON[28906]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 00:17:01 myserver CRON[28905]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 00:19:16 myserver smbd[28548]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
  GNU nano 4.8                                                      hardcopy.0                                                                
Jun 30 01:17:01 myserver CRON[28948]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 01:17:01 myserver CRON[28949]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 01:17:01 myserver CRON[28948]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 01:34:55 myserver systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
Jun 30 01:34:56 myserver systemd[1]: man-db.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 30 01:34:56 myserver systemd[1]: Finished Daily man-db regeneration.
Jun 30 02:17:01 myserver CRON[28997]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 02:17:01 myserver CRON[28998]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 02:17:01 myserver CRON[28997]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 03:10:01 myserver CRON[29035]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 03:10:01 myserver CRON[29036]: (root) CMD (test -e /run/systemd/system || SERVICE_MODE=1 /sbin/e2scrub_all -A -r)
Jun 30 03:10:01 myserver CRON[29035]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 03:17:01 myserver CRON[29042]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 03:17:01 myserver CRON[29043]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 03:17:01 myserver CRON[29042]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 03:22:35 myserver snapd[795]: storehelpers.go:722: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "core18", "core20", "lxd", "snapd
", "zerotier"
Jun 30 03:22:35 myserver snapd[795]: autorefresh.go:539: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
Jun 30 03:29:38 myserver systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs...
Jun 30 03:29:38 myserver systemd[1]: ua-timer.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 30 03:29:38 myserver systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
Jun 30 04:17:01 myserver CRON[29094]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 04:17:01 myserver CRON[29095]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 04:17:01 myserver CRON[29094]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 30 05:17:01 myserver CRON[29132]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jun 30 05:17:01 myserver CRON[29133]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 05:17:01 myserver CRON[29132]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```